# Firebase Messaging: Does it matter if 2 or more users share the same FCM token?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just ran this code to quickly refresh my FCM tokens for 2 test users and I noticed that it wrote the same token to both users. Does it matter that they are the same? Or should they be unique for each user?

```
Future<void> updateFCMToken() async {
    print('##MyApp## updateFCMToken start');
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final uids = ['h7WYC1pohidhpSHqmAEsJfupl3H2','T40yX7hdmdUdZqL5zab3OC0cZOp1'];
    final timestamp = getTimestamp();

    uids.forEach((element) async {
      final userDocRef = firestore.collection(usersCollection).doc(element);
      final newFCMToken = await getFCMToken();
      await userDocRef.update({"fcmToken": newFCMToken, "fcmTokenTimestamp": timestamp});
    });

    print('##MyApp## updateFCMToken end');
  }
```

Comment: FCM targets app instances only (so a specific app on a specific device), and has no knowledge of a user. So if such a relationship exists, it's because your app makes it and it's up to you to ensure the relationship meets your needs. So: when you send a message to a token, what do you expect to happen for each of the users?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I guess I'm kinda confused then. The FCM token represents an app instance right? So since I used 1 device to upload a token for 2 users, if I were to send a notification to a token, then send another to the same token, this means that the same device would receive 2 notifications, correct?

Comment: That's indeed correct. And neither of those messages would be associated with either of the specific users as far as FCM is concerned, since it has no knowledge of a user either way. It just targets the app instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCM targets app instances only (so a specific app on a specific device), and has no knowledge of a user. So if such a relationship exists, it's because your app makes it and it's up to you to ensure the relationship meets your needs.

So if you somehow have the same token for two users, then by definition those two users are using the same app on the same device (as otherwise their tokens would be different). If you send a message to that token, your client-side code will have to determine what user the message is for as FCM has no way to target them. It just targets the app instance identified by the token.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I wasn't understanding FCM tokens correctly, but this cleared it up. Thanks a bunch!!